# Remove Rectangle from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps v3 (javascript). I draw a rectangle in the following way when I load my map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Global variables
  var map;

  /**
   * Called on the initial page load.
   */
  function init() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 6,
      'center': new google.maps.LatLng(41.87194,12.567379999999957),
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    //Region Overlay
    var latLng1;
    var latLng2;

    <?php foreach ($this->arrRegion as $region) { ?>
        latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $region['boundLat1_region']; ?>,<?php echo $region['boundLng1_region']; ?>);
        latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $region['boundLat2_region']; ?>,<?php echo $region['boundLng2_region']; ?>);
        redraw(latLng1,latLng2);
    <?php }?>

  }

  /**
   * Updates the Rectangle's bounds to resize its dimensions.
   */
  function redraw(latLng1,latLng2) {
    var latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latLng1,latLng2);
     // Create a new Rectangle overlay
    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({map: map, bounds: latLngBounds});
  }

  // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

Now, my goal is to remove the rectangle. I try to used map.clear but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 11):

The google.maps.Rectangle class has a setMap method.  If you pass null to that, then the rectangle is removed.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Rectangle

Note that this means that you need to keep instances of your rectangles around so that you can call the setMap method.  The local rectangle variable in your redraw function will not keep it around, unless you call redraw wit the same latLng pairs again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use setMap() function with null input parameter at every redraw() call.

```js
// Global variables
  var map;
  var rectangle;

  /**
   * Called on the initial page load.
   */
  function init() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 6,
      'center': new google.maps.LatLng(41.87194,12.567379999999957),
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    //Region Overlay
    var latLng1;
    var latLng2;

    <?php foreach ($this->arrRegion as $region) { ?>
        latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $region['boundLat1_region']; ?>,<?php echo $region['boundLng1_region']; ?>);
        latLng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $region['boundLat2_region']; ?>,<?php echo $region['boundLng2_region']; ?>);
        redraw(latLng1,latLng2);
    <?php }?>

  }

  /**
   * Updates the Rectangle's bounds to resize its dimensions.
   */
  function redraw(latLng1,latLng2) {
    var latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(latLng1,latLng2);
    
    // Remove Previous Rectangle
    if(rectangle)
      rectangle.setMap(null);
    
     // Create a new Rectangle overlay
    rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({map: map, bounds: latLngBounds});
  }

  // Register an event listener to fire when the page finishes loading.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```